# Creating a podman container as a non-root user in an Ansible playbook running as root

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, namespaces, podman

Is it possible  to create a Podman container under a different user than the one running the Ansible playbook using namespaces?

I am writing an Ansible playbook for my virtual private server. The playbook creates a sudo user, does some configuration, and then installs Podman. I run this playbook using `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --ask-vault-pass --user=root --ask-pass`, so it runs as root (there is no other user after a fresh OS install).

Then it is turn for installing containers. I use the following sample base task:

```yaml
- name: Install Sheetable
  containers.podman.podman_container:
    name: Sheetable
    image: docker.io/vallezw/sheetable
    state: started
    restart_policy: always
    ports:
      - "3333:8080"
    volumes:
      - /home/user/sheetable:/app/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    env:
      ADMIN_EMAIL="{{ sheetable_admin }}"
      ADMIN_PASSWORD="{{ sheetable_password }}"
```

Since this installs as root but I want to install as `user`, following the [official documentation](https://docs.podman.io/en/v4.4/markdown/options/userns.container.html), I have conducted the following tests. For the tests below, `uid=1000` and `gid=1000`, also `<user>:100000:65536` exists in both */etc/subuid* and */etc/subgid* files.

- `userns: "keep-id"`:
  No error, does not create a container at all (neither under  nor root)
- `userns: "keep-id:uid=1000,gid=1000"`:
  No error, does not create a container at all (neither under  nor root)
- `userns: "keep-id:uid=100000,gid=100000"`
  No error, does not create a container at all (neither under  nor root)
- `userns: "auto"` + add `containers:2147483647:2147483648` to */etc/subuid* and */etc/subgid* file:
  No error, does not create a container at all (neither under  nor root)
- `user: 1000:1000` + `userns: "keep-id:uid=1000,gid=1000"`:
  Error: *keep-id is only supported in rootless mode*
- `user: "user:user"` + `userns: "keep-id:uid=1000,gid=1000"`:
  Error: *keep-id is only supported in rootless mode*
- `userns: "auto:uidmapping=0:1000:65536"`:
  No error, creates a container under root.
- `userns: "auto:uidmapping=1000:0:65536"`:
  Errors: *permission denied for mounting storage for container and  creating overlay mount*, *Unmounting /var/lib/containers.../merged: invalid argument*
- `userns: "auto:uidmapping=1000:1000:65536"`:
  Errors: *permission denied for mounting storage for container and  creating overlay mount*, *Unmounting /var/lib/containers.../merged: invalid argument*
- `userns: "ns:<user>"`:
  Errors: *permission denied for mounting storage for container and  creating overlay mount*, *Unmounting /var/lib/containers.../merged: invalid argument*

I know that I can use privilege escalation, and the following task works as intended:

```yaml
- name: Install Sheetable
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ user_name }}"
  containers.podman.podman_container:
    name: Sheetable
    image: docker.io/vallezw/sheetable
    state: started
    restart_policy: always
    ports:
      - "3333:8080"
    volumes:
      - /home/"{{ user_name }}"/sheetable:/app/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    env:
      ADMIN_EMAIL="{{ sheetable_admin }}"
      ADMIN_PASSWORD="{{ sheetable_password }}"
```

But first, I am not sure if it is an OK approach, and second I get the warning

> Module remote_tmp /home/user/.ansible/tmp did not exist and was created with a mode of 0700, this may cause issues when running as another user. To avoid this, create the remote_tmp dir with the correct permissions manually

Is it possible  to create a Podman container under a different user than the one running the Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 0):

You answer lies here --> https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/sudo-rootless-podman

Basically, you have used

```
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ user_name }}"
```

which does not create a login session for this user, hence has issues with running rootless podman. If you want to run this play, ensure you don't use above, but `ssh` into the machine using this user (i.e use `ansible_ssh_user` variable mapped to the user running podman container)